# Enable Virtualization-VT

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, virtualization

Hi my desktop PC is ProLiant ML 110 . and By default this PC doesn't support virtualisation in bios setup.
I need to enable 64 bit system in virtual box , but VB only shows 32 bit.
is there are any way to make it support or enable 64 bit Virtual Box.

Comment: if the hardware does not support it, then you can't

Comment: @PavlosTheodorou the product support of Intel shows that, so any means of over come this or any method to use 64 bit os in virtual box

Comment: in bios is there an option to enable vt ? if not , then you can't use x64. The app stracture is built this way. You can't just rebuild the app to work on x64 without vt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check if the CPU supports VT-x virtualization:

```
lscpu | grep VT-x
```

If the CPU supports VT-x virtualization you will see this result:

```
Virtualization:        VT-x
```

If it does not show this result and the computer doesn't support VT-x virtualization in the BIOS setup, you can't install a 64-bit guest OS in VirtualBox.

You can also check if your computer's CPU supports Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) at the official Intel website by searching the web for `ark <CPU-model>`